# Postgresql: removing spaces between certain type of digits

Tags: postgresql, regexp-replace

I have a column with address such as `'01031 970 São Paulo SP, BR'`.

I want to remove spaces between postal codes. The postal code can appear anywhere in the address, e.g. `'São Paulo 01031 970 SP, BR'`.
The result should be `'São Paulo 01031970 SP, BR'` or `'01031970 São Paulo SP, BR'`

```
regexp_replace(address, ,'(\s*[0-9]{5}\s+[0-9]{3}\s+)','(\s*[0-9]{5}[0-9]{3}\s+)', 'g')
```

obviously does not work, but I am looking for an equivalent that does the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
update your_table
set address = regexp_replace(address, '([0-9]{5})\s+([0-9]{3})', '\1\2', 'g')
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "doesn't work?"  I think my regex is correct.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. Yes, it indeed works if you leave out the `\s*` at the beginning and the `\s+` at the end (as in your regex). Thank you for your help!