# Postgresql: inserting spaces between certain type of digits

Tags: postgresql, regexp-replace

Related to my previous posting
[Postgresql: removing spaces between certain type of digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46234980/postgresql-removing-spaces-between-certain-type-of-digits),
I want to do the opposite, namely to insert spaces between postal codes.
I might have a column with an address such as `'01031970 São Paulo SP, BR'`.

I want to insert a space between the fourth and fifth numeric digit, i.e.
`'0103 1970 São Paulo SP, BR'`.

Any ideas how to do it with `regexp_replace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regexp:

```
select regexp_replace(str, '(^.{4})(.*)', '\1 \2')
from (
    values('01031970 Sao Paulo SP, BR')
    ) v(str);

       regexp_replace       
----------------------------
 0103 1970 Sao Paulo SP, BR
(1 row)
```

Without regexp (may be a bit faster for larger data):

```
select concat(left(str, 4), ' ', right(str, -4))
from (
    values('01031970 Sao Paulo SP, BR')
    ) v(str);

           concat           
----------------------------
 0103 1970 Sao Paulo SP, BR
(1 row)
```